# How to write the following sql query using Criteria Builder?

Tags: java, jpa, criteria, criteria-api, criteriaquery

```
select AVG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ot.end_date -ot.create_date )/3600),count(*), date_trunc('day', ot.update_date)
from ... ot
...
```

How to write the sql query using Criteria Builder? How to use this epoch in Criteria Query?